# How would you translate 'placeholder' to French?

Tags: traduction, anglais

I cannot find a good translation for the computer science term *placeholder*, which could be defined as a symbol that will later be replaced by some other item (for instance, in the text "Bonjour #, comment allez-vous ?", the # character is a placeholder which will be replaced by the name of the user).

The nearest term I could get to is "un substituant", but that's not a user friendly terminology.  I would like to stick to something short and not have to resort to a paraphrase like "le symbole à substituer".

Comment: Je regarderais dans la série des ISO 2382 (disponible ici: http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html) qui définit le vocabulaire en français et en anglais.  Avec le risque de te retrouver avec quelque chose d'aussi commun que _multiplet_ et donc inacceptable.

Comment: Merci. Mais il y en a tellement, des documents liés à ISO 2382, que je n'ai (encore) rien trouvé; autant chercher une aiguille dans une meule de foin -- là au moins, je pourrais utiliser un aimant ;-)

Comment: "Lieutenant": Place...Holder. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly a translation, but would *balise* (tag) fit? (If you're dealing with users who are sufficiently non-technical to not get confused with 'real' tags).

Comment: Balise est aussi le terme utilisé dans ma société.

Comment: *Marqueur* ou *balise* me semblent être les traductions les plus adaptées. Au travail, j'ai souvent trouvé "balise" dans les documentations rédigées en français, mais si je lisais "marquer" je comprendrais également. Ce n'est probablement pas le cas des autres traductions proposées.

Answer (score 18):

La première idée qui me vient à l'esprit est *substitut* qui rejoint l'idée de *substituant*.

On peut trouver aussi les traductions suivantes [dans un dictionnaire](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertaal/EN/FR/placeholder): *paramètre substituable*, *espace réservé*, *paramètre fictif*, *marque de réservation* ; mais aucun ne paraît vraiment convaincant. A noter cependant que ***paramètre*** revient deux fois, et en ça je rejoins l'avis de Nicolas Raoul : je pense aussi que c'est le plus adapté.

Sinon, *variable* convient bien aussi; et dans un registre plus mathématique, *inconnue* devrait aussi pouvoir faire l'affaire.

Passant outre le litéral *garde-place*, il reste à trouver une tournure tout aussi inutile mais plus imagée. Je propose donc *serviette de plage* (ou juste *serviette*), en référence aux touristes qui s'en servent pour réserver leur chaise longue. L'avantage d'une image est qu'elle est plus facile à retenir... et pourquoi pas, finalement?

Comment: J'aime bien la notion de *serviette de plage*, malheureusement, ça risque de ne pas être compris. Vous imaginez les appels à l'assistance technique: le programme me demande de lui donner une serviette de plage :-)

Comment: C'est trop long.  Si on veux traduire le mot "placeholder" pour une interface graphique, on veux probablement un mot de longueur similaire, comme "substitut"...

Comment: Heureusement que j'ai le pretexte de la langue pour moinssoyer (et *balise* répond vraiment bien, voire mieux (en plus de faire penser à *bouée*…)), c'est vraiment une trop bonne réponse.

Comment: pourquoi fictif ? n'est-ce pas superflu ?

Answer (score 7):

I would use **blanc (s.m.)** in most cases:

> Dans la phrase « Bonjour _______, comment allez-vous ? », que mettre à la place du blanc ?

Comment: Simple et efficace.

Comment: +1 But the word *"placeholder"* seems to imply that a generic text is used *in place of* the final text. That's not exactly the same as a blank space.

Comment: On the contrary, I would say it is: the _blanc_ **is** a generic item used in place of the final text. It does hold the place nicely for the final text to come. Note that eventhough it says _blanc_, it doesn't mean the space has to be left blank; hence the use of an underline showing clearly that it needs to be filled later.

Comment: Ok, but the software design world sometimes requires the placeholder to be something else than underscores or series of dots. In OP's case, the placeholder is a sharp sign, and does not look at all like a blank sign...

Comment: -1 parce que ça ne correspond pas au sens donné dans le contexte. Le `#` `{}` `%1` `%s` etc. n'est pas un _blanc à complété_ commen dans un formulaire, mais sert d'emplacement à un texte de substitution.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure there is such a translation.

I have been using the English word *"placeholder"* in the middle of discussions in French to refer to those. In the specific case of a dummy text in a field for example, *"texte par défaut"* (*default text*) could do the trick, with the caveat that a placeholder is not always a default value.

For your example, I seen people use the English term *"wildcard"*, and maybe you could use *"variable"*, *"paramètre"* or *"jeton"*, but none of them sound quite correct. The closest I can think of at the moment would be *"substitut"*, but it would sound a bit unusual. It is a matter of habit too after all.

If I were to come up with a word for this, I guess I would propose *"capsule"*, which conveys the idea of something empty that is yet to be filled. But nobody would understand if I were to use it. :)

As a last attempt: *"emplacement"* ?

Comment: -1 for¹ not being sure. There are *plenty* of possibilities—even though not many good ones—and if he *needs* something there there's *always* a translation (be it 10 words long). I'd agree with "no one-word translation will carry as well its meaning". ¹ Also mostly because less upvoted answers deserve to climb this question's ladder.

Comment: I stand by my answer: I don't see the point of suggesting a translation that is not a good one. A translation that sounds weird or that people will not understand is not a good one. A 10 words long translation is not a translation anymore, it's an explanation, a description.

Answer (score 4):

Une variable métasyntactique ou métasyntaxique ?

Sinon, "substituant" est bien, et tu peux tout-à-fait l'expliquer : "un objet fictif qui sera substitué par une donnée lors de…"

Comment: certes, mais c'est un peu abscons pour un utilisateur lambda.

Comment: Il faut préciser qui est ta cible ! Si ton article est pour des informaticiens, alors je pense que ma réponse est l'une des plus adéquates. Si c'est pour ta grand-mère, alors oui, il faudra un autre mot…

Comment: Tu as raison. Mon public cible est un utilisateur non informaticien, mais professionnel (par ex. un comptable qui doit configurer son application).

Comment: +1 pour l'efficacité de la technicité. @Pierre : Pour l'utilisateur, je recommande le [blanc de F'x](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/801/1514), terme des plus compréhensibles.

Answer (score 3):

Le mot "paramètre" conviendrait-il?

Le [dictionnaire de l'Office québécois de la langue française](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26532924) donne cette traduction: "paramètre fictif"

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres: Corrigé, merci !

Answer (score 3):

La plupart des services de traduction proposent "paramètre" ou "paramètre fictif".

Je pense que l'expression mandataire serait plus représentative du concept, car le *placeholder* n'est pas qu'un paramètre:

> mandataire masculin (féminin : mandatrice)
>   Celui qui est chargé d'un mandat, d'une procuration, d'une mission pour agir au nom d’un autre. [1](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mandataire)

On peut aussi voir cela comme un "élément de substitution", une "ébauche" (mais je n'aime pas trop celui-ci car connote plus des élément physique), un "patron" (dans un sens similaire à la couture, ou la peinture) ou une "maquette".

Comment: Je crois que le *paramètre* est probablement le plus compréhensible par l'utilisateur, même s'il n'est de loin pas le plus précis.

Comment: pour moi, le mandataire rapporte plutôt à la notion de "proxy"… Je préfère aussi *paramètre*.

Comment: -1 parce que généralement, je fais varier mes paramètres (alors que le *placeholder* n'est pas à paramétrer, mais à évincer), et que les autres propositions n'ont pas vraiment d'allure… « Élément de substitution » est presque correct, mais on est loin de la beauté du mot unique.

Answer (score 3):

Selon le "Grand dictionnaire terminologique du Québec", le terme est "paramètre fictif" (base sur une traduction d'IBM en 1989.

http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18957324

Comment: Je n'ai jamais eu l'occasion d'entendre ce terme au Luxembourg (où je travaille ; nous utilisons souvent _placeholder_) mais j'aime l'idée qu'il véhicule.

Comment: Ce lien n'existe plus, je retrouve cependant la référence à IBM [ici](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=placeholder&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), mais relativement à une date antérieure. Autrement, au _GDT_, voir [ici](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26532924) alors qu'on ajoute aussi _emplacement réservé_, _marque substitutive/de réservation_ et _espace réservé_.

Answer (score 2):

J'aurais tendance à parler tout simplement de **trou**, de **pointillés** pour *placeholder*, comme il est d'usage de remplir les textes à trous suivant les pointillés

Comment: J'aime bien l'idée du trou qui prend de la place.

Answer (score 1):

J'utiliserais le verbe marquer pour décrire la fonction de '#', sans le qualifier par un nom.

> Le caractère # marque l'endroit où insérer le nom de l'utilisateur.

D'autres verbes possibles : montrer, indiquer, signaler.

Comment: Le hic, c'est que je dois ensuite parler du "#" dans les explications; exemple: *texte de remplacement pour #*

Comment: Dans ce cas, utiliser le mot "marqueur", en faisant attention de toujours utiliser le verbe marquer, et d'avoir un glossaire quelque part qui explique le sens de "marquer / marqueur" dans le contexte de l'application.

Comment: C'est-à-dire que ça ne ressemble pas tout à fait à une traduction. (Et *marqueur* ne me convaic guère.)

Answer (score 1):

Je suis informaticien, et j'ai souvent rencontré *placeholder* pour évoquer un **paramètre** ou encore un **argument**, c'est-à-dire une expression qui peut (ou doit) arriver en complément d'une autre.

Par exemple :

> […] pattern:   /blog/{page} […]
>
> Like the {slug} placeholder before, the value matching {page} will be available inside your controller.

On voit bien ici que `{page}` est un **argument** facultatif.

Comment: Bienvenue sur french.stackexchange :·) *Argument* me semble *a bit of a stretch* pour traduire *placeholder*, et m'évoque beaucoup plus quelque chose qui sera passé à une fonction, ce qui est loin d'être toujours le cas (*paramètre* a déjà été proposé plusieurs fois).

Comment: D'accord avec @LeVieuxGildas, ça a plus l'air d'un cas particulier. Mais tu as peut-être une référence ?

Answer (score 1):

"A placeholder for..." → un emplacement réservé à...

Therefore, the explanation:

> in the text "Bonjour #, comment allez-vous ?", the # character is a placeholder for the name of the user.

would become:

> Dans le texte "Bonjour #, comment allez-vous ?", le caractère # est *un emplacement réservé* au nom de l'utilisateur.

Comment: Welcome to FL StackExchange! Please add content to your answer. You may add exemples to see in which context it is used...

Answer (score 0):

Il y a deux notions:

- identifiant ou balise ou marqueur, qui physiquement pointe le #

de

- paramètre ou variable, qui donne la fonction (de remplacement)

Cela fait déjà 9 combinaisons.

Answer (score 0):

La terminologie de MS Word utilise *champ*:

> Mettre à jour les champs.

Comment: Moui. Je ne me vois pas écrire "le caractère # est le _champ_ se référant au nom de l'utilisateur", parce que c'est pas vraiment un champ. Justement, c'est un _placeholder_.

Answer (score 0):

Voici quelques propositions pour remplacer *placeholder text* :

- entrée fictive
- texte-exemple
- texte-à-substituer
- suggestion d'entrée
- contenu-type
- spécimen
- spécimen de saisie

Si l'on tient compte de la longueur du texte lors de la traduction :

> *placeholder text* : 14 caractères plus une espace
>   *texte-à-substituer* : 15 caractères plus deux tirets

**spécimen de saisie** est ma formule préférée.